# Handlebars (hbs) files in html-design.zip

Tags: dxa

What is the purpose of the Handlebars (hbs) files within the html-design.zip used for DXA? It is my understanding that the HTML is rendered through the views of your web application, completely separating this concern from Tridion publishing, so I'm not sure what the point of storing any templating code in the CM is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bart explains in [this Prezi](https://prezi.com/dq18gpnjwrmz/dxa-html-design/), the design for your DXA site can be built locally. I believe these handlebars templates are used for this, and allow for a static site to be built independent of your web application, meaning you can do front end development without having to rezip your files and upload them for each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the HTML is rendered by the Views in the MVC Web App, but the HTML design contains the stylesheets and client-side logic (Javascript) used to render that HTML in the browser.

Comment: I understand the stylesheets and JS being in this zip file since they're built and deployed to my web application, but I also see handlesbars template files being included in the example zip. As far as I can tell these don't contribute to the final web application.